# Interface to work with the Task Scheduler

Tags: scheduled-tasks, jscript, wsh

I'm developing a simple `JScript` script to be run by `Windows Script Host`.

This script needs to read some data from the Task Scheduler. I have no clue how to get started.

I've already implemented similar functionality in c++ using [Task Scheduler 2.0 Interfaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383600(v=vs.85).aspx)

Can I use those interfaces in `JScript` somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't use the Task Scheduler 2.0 interfaces from JScript.

What you can do however, is read the XML files that the task scheduler creates. They contain all properties of all defined tasks.

They reside in `%windir%\system32\tasks` (you need Administrator permissions to read this directory and its contents).

Here is an example of such a file, it's very straightforward XML:

```
<Task version="1.1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <RegistrationInfo>
    <Author>SYSTEM</Author>
    <Description>Some text here...</Description>
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers>
    <LogonTrigger>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    </LogonTrigger>
    <CalendarTrigger>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
      <StartBoundary>2015-07-16T05:32:00</StartBoundary>
      <ScheduleByDay>
        <DaysInterval>1</DaysInterval>
      </ScheduleByDay>
    </CalendarTrigger>
  </Triggers>
  <Settings>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <ExecutionTimeLimit>PT0S</ExecutionTimeLimit>
    <Hidden>false</Hidden>
    <WakeToRun>false</WakeToRun>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>false</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>false</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
    <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
    <Priority>5</Priority>
    <IdleSettings>
      <Duration>PT600S</Duration>
      <WaitTimeout>PT3600S</WaitTimeout>
      <StopOnIdleEnd>false</StopOnIdleEnd>
      <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
    </IdleSettings>
  </Settings>
  <Principals>
    <Principal id="Author">
      <UserId>System</UserId>
      <RunLevel>HighestAvailable</RunLevel>
      <LogonType>InteractiveTokenOrPassword</LogonType>
    </Principal>
  </Principals>
  <Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
      <Command>C:\path\to\executable.exe</Command>
      <Arguments>/args</Arguments>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>
```

List of things to find out:

- How to run a script with elevated permissions.
- How to navigate a directory structure using the FileSystemObject.
- How to open XML files using the MSXML2 COM objects
- How to use XPath to navigate those XML documents.
- How to deal with a default XML namespace (this is more important than it sounds - you won't get any results from XPath until you did this part correctly).
- If necessary for your task, find out how ISO 8601 time period notation works so you can decode values like `PT600S`.

Luckily, for all of those things there are any number of examples available (on this site and elsewhere) to get you started.

Comment: 10x. does it work in XP and in 64bit system (same path)?

Comment: Yes, the path is the same.

Comment: What about using WMI? I tried using `Win32_ScheduledJob`. Unfortunately: *"The Win32_ScheduledJob WMI class represents a job created with the AT command. The Win32_ScheduledJob class does not represent a job created with the Scheduled Task Wizard from the Control Panel. You cannot change a task created by WMI in the Scheduled Tasks UI"*

Comment: What's wrong with the approach I skeched out? Just try it, it's far less difficult than you might think.

Comment: Actually I can't find anything wrong. Already started using it. But before I go and read/parse the files myself (although it is quite easy), I'd like to know what are the possible approaches to tackle this.

Comment: Fair enough. For me, simply parsing an XML file is preferable to figuring out *yet another* API abstraction that basically goes and reads the same XML file after all, but of course using an API is cleaner than accessing the raw data.